# version of aggregate event sourcing

Tags: aggregate, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, domain-events

According to event sourcing. When a command is called, all events of a domain have to be stored.
 Per event, system must increase the version of an aggregate. My eventstore is something like this:
(AggregateId, AggregateVersion, Sequence, Data, EventName, CreatedDate)
**(AggregateId, AggregateVersion) is key**
In some cases it does not make sense to increase the version of an aggregate. For example,
a command register an user and raises RegisteredUser, WelcomeEmailEvent, GiftCardEvent.

how can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

> how can I handle this problem?

Avoid confusing your representation-of-information-changes events from your publishing-for-use-elsewhere events.

"Event sourcing", as commonly understood in the `domain-drive-design` and `cqrs` space, is a kind of *data model*.  We're talking specifically about the messages an aggregate *sends to its future self* that describe its own changes over time.

It's "just" another way of storing the state of the aggregate, same as we would do if we were storing information in a relational database, or a document store, etc.

Messages that we are going to send to other components and then forget about don't need to have events in the event stream.

---

In some cases, there can be confusion when we haven't recognized that there are multiple different processes at work.

A requirement like "when a new user is registered, we should send them a welcome email" is not necessarily part of the registration process; it might instead be an independent process that is triggered by the appearance of a `RegisteredUser` event.  The information that you need to save for the SendEmail process would be "somewhere else" - outside of the Users event history.

Answer (score 1):

Event changes the state of an aggregate, and therefore changes its version. If state is not changed, then there should be no event for this aggregate.

In your example, I would ask myself - if WelcomeEmailEvent does not change the state of the User aggregate, then whose state it chages? Perhaps some other aggregate - some EmailNotification service that cares about successful or filed email attempt. In this case I would make it event of those aggregate which state it changes. And it will affect version of that aggregate.